# Measuring distance between wavey lines/points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, parallel-lines, circularstring

[image]

In I want to design meandering lines on a plot at 5m distance apart. I am using the circular string tool so it's all by hand, ideally, they would be identical lines with a consistent 5m distance.

How do I achieve this, or how do I check the distance between the lines once drawn, is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

1. Draw a straight line
2. Use it as input to geometry by expression with the formula: `wave($geometry, 500, 50)` . You will have to adjust 500 and 50 (wavelength and amplitude)
3. Buffer with 2.5 meters
4. Polygons to line
5. Start editing on the lines, Use split features to split at the buffer ends and delete the ends to end up with the two parallell lines:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the wave expression. Very cool!

Comment: Newly introduced in QGIS 3.24 (I think - or 3.22)

Comment: @Fezter, [QGIS 3.24](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-expression-functions-for-creating-triangular-square-curved-waves) is going to be a really good release